# Google Analytics API not sending complete data

Tags: google-analytics-api

I have used Google Analytics API in C# to fetch analytics data. But it doesn't send complete data. For eg. If I check for the month of March total number of events under PDF Download in Analytics Dashboard, it shows following:
[Analytics Dashboard Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzYb2.png)

But when I check it with the data fetched by API it give following numbers:

[image]

Both of these numbers are very different to each other and this is the case for all the months.

I don't have any filters applied. Can anyone suggest why these numbers are different?

Answer (score 0):

If you are grabbing a really long timeframe with the API, it might be sampling your result there.

You might also check that you're grabbing the correct view.

Comment: There is no problem with the view id. And I feel sampling is done when view is shown on GA site. Sampling helps GA site to render graph faster. When fetching data using API, it should send complete data, why will it sample it?

Comment: "Sampled" data can be returned with the API.  Search for the word sampled in your results.  It is a "True"/"False" flag.  I also believe if you upgrade to the Google Analytics Premium you will always get un-sampled data.  But this is also $100,000/year.

Comment: I've also had issues with third party API resources (like this one I used for SSIS a while back) having settings set that messed with the data slightly. They should definitely match exactly.